# I get the following error when running npm build

Tags: node.js, npm, bootstrap-4

```json
{
    "name": "confusion",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "lite-server": "^2.4.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
        "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
        "onchange": "^3.3.0",
        "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
        "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
        "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run watch:all",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
        "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
        "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\"",
        "clean": "rimraf dist",
        "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts",
        "imagemin": "imagemin img/* -o dist/img",
        "usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",
        "build": "npm run clean && npm run imagemin && npm run copyfonts && npm run usemin"
    }
}

C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion>npm run build

> confusion@1.0.0 build C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> npm run clean && npm run imagemin && npm run copyfonts && npm run usemin

> confusion@1.0.0 clean C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> rimraf dist

> confusion@1.0.0 imagemin C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> imagemin img/* -o dist/img

4 images minified

> confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts

> confusion@1.0.0 usemin C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html

undefined:1625
    throw new JS_Parse_Error(message, filename, line, col, pos);
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\username\Documents\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\usemin\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:27:1), <anonymous>:86:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 usemin: `usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 usemin script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-24T21_38_01_183Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && npm run imagemin && npm run copyfonts && npm run usemin`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing the same course and had the same errors. However, I was just able to fix it. I did this by reinstalling all dev dependencies and used the current versions, not the ones in the course. 
I did also change the usemin command (according to the post here) to

"imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir=dist/img",

However, it still did not work, so I checked all my files for errors using the following tools:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html for testing the html files; http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html, for testing the .js file and https://jsonlint.com/?json=, to test the package.json file for errors.

After I did correct all the files, the command "npm run build" did finally work. (I especially forgot to check the script.js file where I just copied the code from the html file that still contained the script tags)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using ES6 syntax but ES5 presets.

Add the `babel-preset-es2015` dependency to fix this.

And also add `'es2015'` in .babelrc file.

```
json
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: The error is still there, The issue is with usemin. 
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 usemin: `usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Follow the GitHub page of imagemin, it has the solution:
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-cli

Replace
`"imagemin": "imagemin img/* -o dist/img",`

with
`"imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir=dist/img",`

Answer (score 0):

> the issue might be in your scripts.js file but first, try to do the
>   next test, step by step.

from your package.json ... change

```
"imagemin": "imagemin img/* -o dist/img",
```

to

```
"imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir dist/img/",
```

and change (only add another *.html file, but now we'll trying with only one *.html file)

```
"usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html",
```

to

```
"usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist -o dist/contactus.html --htmlmin true",
```

**if doesn't work, keep the changes and try this**

from your *.html ... change

```
   <!-- build:js js/main.js -->
   <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
```

to

```
   <!-- build:js js/main.js -->
   <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

run

```
npm run usemin
```

> if see your dist folder and the complete path with css and js
>   folders and html files; the conclusion is, you need to check the
>   syntax of JavaScript from you scripts.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck to that error too for the same course task.
I was just able to fix it by `only` reinstalling `usemin-cli`, `cssmin`, `uglify-js` and `htmlmin` dev dependencies by the current versions without specify any by :

```
sudo npm install --save-dev usemin-cli cssmin uglify-js htmlmin
```

then

```
npm run build
```

then I found all the files including html which make the usemin problems inside dist folder.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it the error with the version try writing

**npm install -g imagemin-cli**

instead of

**npm install -g imagemin-cli@"version"**

Answer (score -2):

I am running the same course, and after read, and search, I realize scripts.js is the winner, currently, the code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(()=>
 ...
```

Just need to change to this:

$(function(){
...

Please, refer to jquery documentation :[jQuery official](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler)

Comment: Why should an arrow function not work? Works very well for me, see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce9xjz43/1/). Furthermore the question is about a npm build and not about jQuery?!

Comment: Where does the question mention a file scripts.js? Did you maybe post this to the wrong question?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks man, I was facing the same issues,
What i did is,
I ran individual components starting from imagemin. I had an error with it so I ran

`sudo npm install imagemin imagemin-cli`

next i ran usemin, and with individual html, i found that except index rest all htmls were fine so I used a html validator and found some errors in the html i fixed those errors and now everything worked.

Comment: However, when I checked my index.html file it contained a lot of errors and wasn't well formatted ,but after changing these errors your answer doesn't work too.